# ObservableCollection and Handlers

Tags: .net, vb.net

Say, I have an ObservableCollection

```
Class Person
  Name
  Event DidSomething

Class House
  WithEvents People as ObservableCollection(of Person)

  Sub OnPersonDidSomething(p as Person)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} did something", p.Name)
```

Now, how I should implement the handler of this ObservableCollection?

```
Private Sub People_CollectionChanged( _ 
  sender As Object, _ 
  e As NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs) Handles People.CollectionChanged

Select Case e.Action
  Case Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add
    For Each mp As Person In e.NewItems
      RemoveHandler mp.DidSomething, AddressOf OnPersonDidSomething
      AddHandler mp.DidSomething, AddressOf OnPersonDidSomething
    Next mp

  Case Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove
    For Each mp As Person In e.NewItems
      RemoveHandler mp.DidSomething, AddressOf OnPersonDidSomething
    Next mp
End Select

End Sub
```

Is it correct? What to to for the `Move, Replace, Reset` actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct.

For `Replace`, you should remove handlers from the old items and add them to the new items.

For `Reset`, you should panic, because you cannot know which items were removed or added.

Comment: For Reset should I Remove handler for all OldItems, and add a New one for the Actual ones?

Comment: Good question.  You should remove and add to the old and new items, but I believe they'll be empty.  To avoid leaking memory, you may need to maintain a separate collection of known items to remove from (then add to everything currently in the collection)

Comment: Looking at the source, `Reset` is only raised when calling `Clear()`, and does not give you the old items.  Either don't support `Clear()` or make a separate list to track old items.

Comment: but when calling Clear() the `Remove` event is never fired?

Comment: @serhio: Correct.  (annoyingly)